# Get ith, in O(h) where h is the tree height

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

Description: determine the ith smallest element. If i is outside of range return false, otherwise true.

I have tried to implement different versions and this is the only way that I go mine to work but not in O(h).

```
 bool get_ith(int i, T &x) {
      int n = size();
      int sofar=0;

      if(i < 1 || i > n)
        return false;

      _get_ith(root, i, x, sofar);
      return true;
    }

  private:
    // recursive helper function that does most of the work
    static void _get_ith(bst_node *t, int i, T &x, int &sofar) {
      if(t==nullptr)
        return;
      _get_ith(t->left, i, x, sofar);

      if(sofar==i)
        return;
      sofar++;
      if(sofar==i) {
        x = t->val;
        return;
      }
      _get_ith(t->right, i, x, sofar);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For each node, keep track of the number of nodes in its subtree. Update this number when you perform operations involving this subtree.

When you need to find the `i`th smallest element in a subtree, you would look at the number of nodes in the left subtree of the root node. If that number is greater than or equal to `i` (assuming `i` is one-indexed), the desired node is in the left subtree and you can recurse/iterate on that. If the number is exactly `i - 1`, the current node is the desired node. Otherwise, the desired node is the `i - (leftcount + 1)`th node in the right subtree, and you can recurse/iterate appropriately.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on how to implement what you mean, can you write a pseudo code? So I can see what you are trying to express.

Comment: @JCoding Which part are you confused about?